# ImageMagick NegativeOrZeroImageSize .emf

Tags: imagemagick

I'm using `Wine` on Ubuntu 16.04 and `ImageMagick-7.0.3-5-portable-Q16-x64` to convert `.emf` files to `.png`.

The .emf file is `44.8 MB` and has dimensions `3264x2448`

I'm using the following from inside the portable folder:

`wine convert.exe ../test.emf ../test.png`

which errors with:

```
fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x23b850 (nil)): stub
convert.exe: NegativeOrZeroImageSize `../test.emf' @ error/image.c/SetImageExtent/2453.
convert.exe: NoImagesDefined `../test.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3253.
```

So perhaps it's failing to get the size of the emf?

`wine identify.exe -ping -format '%w %h' ../test.emf`

Which errors with

```
identify.exe: NegativeOrZeroImageSize `../test.emf' @ error/image.c/SetImageExtent/2453.
```

Note, I ran `indentify.exe` on a test `../test.jpg` image and it worked correctly so I know the paths are correct.